# how to turn file:/// into normal path like : S:/soft/abc/xy.txt by C# code

Tags: c#, file

like :

```
file:///S:/soft/abc/EncryptionREBUILD/GenCertII/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/GencateII.dll
```

...turn into :

```
S:\soft\abc\EncryptionREBUILD\GenCertII\bin/Debug\netcoreapp3.1\GencateII.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the `file:///` from the start:

```
str = "file:///S:/soft/abc/EncryptionREBUILD/GenCertII/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/GencateII.dll";
str.Remove(0, 8); /* remove first 8 characters from string */
```

2. Replace all `/`'s with `\`'s (note that `\` must be escaped)

```
str.Replace('/', '\\');
```

### See also

- [String.Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=netcore-3.1)
- [String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to edit your question and add some explanation because it's quite easy to store it in a variable, then use `string.Remove(0,8)` to remove first 8 chars.

Then replace `/` with `\` using `string.Replace('/','\\\\')` and thats it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netcore-3.1) class for this:

```
var str = "file:///S:/soft/abc/EncryptionREBUILD/GenCertII/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/GencateII.dll";
var uri = new Uri(str);
if (uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeFile)
{
    var path = uri.LocalPath;
    // path = @"S:\soft\abc\EncryptionREBUILD\GenCertII\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\GencateII.dll"
}
```

Comment: OH,I see, it is  a  network address begin with "file"  ,like rtsp://  , Ftp://   http://    thank you!!!